# How to process requests for certain sub-domain(s) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

For example, I want my project link to look like `http://blog.example.com`. How can I make that kind of route in Rails 4? And how it can interact with controller?

The following stuff didn't work for me.

```
resource :article, constraints: {subdomain: 'blog'}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the title of your question be "How to process requests for certain sub-domain(s) in Rails?"

Answer (score 1):

Your code is acting as a type of filter, so only requests already utilizing the subdomain 'blog' will invoke the route. You need to ensure that the web server itself is also setup to handle that subdomain and point it to your application.

Edit: Try checking out this post for further clarification (if you're on your local environment). https://reinteractive.net/posts/199-developing-and-testing-rails-applications-with-subdomains